# How to automatically rotate images based on EXIF data?

Tags: macos, jpeg, automator, rotate, exiftool

I know how to [do it manually](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/tut02/index.html). Now I would like to automate that based on EXIF data.
I already have `exiftool` installed, but looks like it can only read the data, but can not rotate the image.

There is [a similar question on SU about Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/36645/how-to-rotate-images-automatically-based-on-exif-data). But I'm looking for possible solutions using OSX.

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/36653/195224) to your quoted question mentions XnView. In the meantime there ist also XnViewMP which is very similar, but runs also under [MacOS](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `nconvert`, which is freeware (for private and educational use) and available for [Win, Linux and Mac](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/#downloads).

This tool can rotate JPEG images *lossless* according to the EXIF orientation tag:

```
nconvert -jpegtrans exif -o 'rotated_%.jpg' *.jpg
```

That command will batch convert all JPEG files in the current directory and prepending their names with `rotated_`. This is controlled by the `-o` option, refer to `nconvert -help` for more possibilities:

```
-o filename       : Output filename
   Use # to specify position of numeric enumerator
   Use % to specify source filename
   Use $ to specify full source pathname
   Use $$ to specify source folder name
```

Comment: Thank, mpy. Where should I place `nconvert` once downloaded and unpacked (so that it will be available by name only)? I've tried to moved it to Applications, but it didn't help.

Comment: @LA_ : Into some directory which is in your PATH (check the output of `echo $PATH`). Under linux a usual place is `~/bin`, but I can't say anything about OSX, sorry. Under some circumstances you have to issue `rehash` (or start a new terminal) after moving an executable to another dir.

Answer (score 15):

You may use the free [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) (which itself uses [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/)).

To fix a picture named "image.jpg" just type :

```
jhead -autorot image.jpg
```

To fix all JPGs having EXIF data in the current folder use :

```
jhead -autorot *.jpg
```

If once rotated the thumbnail icons do not show correctly, you could refresh them by :

1. Create a new folder (keep the untitled name)
2. Move the affected images into the folder
3. Using Column View, move the images back into the original folder
4. Delete the empty untitled folder

Comment: This is my favorite - I remembered jpegtran to have some trouble with stripping EXIF data. A must have before sending pictures over e-mail, which will be viewed with Chrome or other browser not respecting EXIF orientation!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a scripted solution. I like this way as it allows me to change another aspects of the photos in one step.

Possible simple solution is to use Google Picasa.

After adding pictures in, all photos are autorotated for displaying. If the picture should be autorotated in the file, it is enough to push the save button on the picture folder. This will save all pictures in the folder with corrected rotation. Picasa is available for OS X as well and runs in Linux under Wine.

Comment: Picasa has been discontinued by Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Automator for this you can simply use Rotate Images (180deg) twice in the workflow.

For example I use an automator action that converts all images to JPEG, rotates them 360deg (due to the OP's issue) and then scales them to 1024px wide.  Run the action, select the files, profit! :)

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows graphical interface, there's JPEG Autorotate which uses jpegtran under the hood.

[www.jpegrotate.com](http://www.jpegrotate.com)

Disclaimer: I made this.