# Scale images into a square with ffmpeg: EXIF orientation lost

Tags: ffmpeg, images

I'd like to use this command to scale, pad and rotate several jpeg images into a common 1000x1000 output resolution:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -vf "scale=1000:1000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=1000:1000:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" square.jpg
```

However (EXIF) portrait orientation is not preserved into the output image...

Input:

[image]

Expected output on the left, what I get on the right:

[image: Expected]  [image: Obtained]

From different questions on the site, I'm assuming ffmpeg identifies orientation itself and processes images accordingly. Or is that valid only for video streams?

Using latest ffmpeg (4.0.2).

Comment: *valid only for video streams* -> generally, yes. FFmpeg does not induce oritentation from EXIF.

Comment: @Gyan: Too bad, does that mean FFmpeg values `iw` and `ih` will be the same regardless of the mode landscape/portrait?

Comment: They will represent dimensions of the decoded raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying images according to their EXIF orientation is a feature that is more
common to image editors or image handling libraries.

I suggest to rotate first all images to their true orientation.

For methods of doing the rotation, see the post
[How to automatically rotate images based on EXIF data?](https://superuser.com/questions/670818/how-to-automatically-rotate-images-based-on-exif-data)