# Autorotate images (and overwrite them) to match orientation

Tags: windows-7, windows, images

I made a photo with my Samsung phone and:

1. The orientation is good when displayed on the phone
2. The orientation is good when displayed in Picasa (this means the JPG files contains the right orientation metadata!)

[image]

3. The orientation is **wrong** when displayed in Windows 7 Explorer thumbnail:

[image]

4. The orientation is **wrong** when displayed in Windows 7 Image viewer:

[image]

One solution could be to "forget about Windows 7's built-in image viewer", and use another better image viewer, **but I don't want this**.

**I would like to permanently rewrite the JPG files (and overwrite them) with the new good orientation, in bulk for hundreds of JPG files**, i.e. like if I clicked manually hundreds of times on these buttons when viewing the images one after another:

[image]

but automatically, with a script.

**How to do this?**

Note: I know it might *not* be lossless, but still I would like a permanent rotation so that the default Windows 7 image viewer see them with the good orientation.

Note 2: [here is the source file](http://gget.it/j43lsdht/20180312_175145.jpg), available for download.

Comment: It should be noted that Google ended support for Picasa in 2016.

Comment: You're right @Burgi, but I still think it's still a wonderful image viewer, and their face recognition is still amazing (I haven't found another standalone offline software that has such a powerful "automatically group photos by people" algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download `jpegtran` from here: http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/. Direct link to [jpegtran.exe](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran.exe). You won't need to run this .exe yourself, but it will be necessary for `jhead` (see next point) to work. `jpegtran` is a tool that can perform, according to its home page, "lossless rotation and related transforms".
- Download `jhead` from here: http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/. Direct link to [jhead.exe](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/jhead.exe). `jhead` is an "Exif Jpeg header manipulation tool", that will read the orientation metadata inside the JPG, and pass it to `jpegtran` for rotation, if necessary.
- Just run

  ```
  jhead -autorot *.jpg
  ```

and that's it!

This [question](https://superuser.com/a/38860/221041) was useful, I added details to make it easy to use from the perspective of a Windows user.

Note: Sometimes, an error can happen for some file, preventing the processing to continue for the other files, this is annoying. Then `for /r %i in (*.jpg) do jhead -autorot "%i"` can help in this case. [If it's in a batch file, use `for /r %%Mi in (*.jpg) do jhead -autorot "%%i"`]

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what these applications do and why/how they solve your problem? Please see [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: I added some details @Burgi.